# Python: Error: 'tuple' object has no attribute

Tags: python, file-io, tuples

```
#   Log to File
#This function logs line number, time, and message in log.txt
def log(msg):
    global LOG_CNT
    LOG_CNT += 1
    lineNumber = getframeinfo(currentframe()).lineno
    dts = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    f = open('log.txt', 'a')
    f.write('Log %d: Line %s: %s: %s\n' % (LOG_CNT, lineNumber, dts, msg))
    f.close()
```

Giving following error when calling the function: log("Test")

```
[error] script [ AutoSTO ] stopped with error in line 833
[error] AttributeError ( 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lineno' )
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first line: module ( function ) statement 72: main ( log ) lineNumber = getframeinfo(currentframe()).lineno
[error] --- Traceback --- end --------------
```

Comment: If that is `inspect.getframeinfo`, then it should be returning an `inspect.Traceback` instance.  Did you somehow redefine `getframeinfo` so that it returns a tuple?

Comment: Are you using `inspect.getframeinfo` ?

Answer (score 0):

inspect.getframeinfo function return Traceback a named tuple type,and lineno may be the attribute of a member in the returned tuple object